# How to include subproject classes in jar?

Tags: java, gradle

After hours of researching and trying I hope that someone can explain how we can have Gradle including classes of one or more subproject into a specific jar.

Lets say we have just three modules

1. Core
2. App
3. Web

Obviously the `App` and `Web` project artifacts (jars) should contain all classes from the `Core` project.

Settings gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'MyProject'
include 'MyProjectCore'
include 'MyProjectApp'
include 'MyProjectWeb'
```

MyProjectApp / MyProjectWeb:

```
...
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':MyProjectCore')
}
```

The projects can be compiled but the output jars do not contain the core classes.

Comment: What kind of target package are you trying to build? If it should later be deployed to an application server (I'm assuming this as there is a 'web' sub project involved) you could also try gradle's ear or war plugin. There are specialized dependency scopes in order to add sub jars/wars the way you desire it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay finally I found a working solution even if it might not be the best.

For the `App` and `Web` projects I overwrite the `jar` task like this to add the source sets of the `Core` module.

```
jar {
    from project.sourceSets.main.allSource
    from project(":MyProjectCore").sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the missing piece I needed after reading the excellent tutorial on multi-project build at https://rominirani.com/gradle-tutorial-part-3-multiple-java-projects-5b1c4d1fbd8d . One comment hough, using `sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs` for the core project `from` resulted in inclusion of the .java and .class files in my jar file. I switched to `sourceSets.main.output` and now am getting only the .class files

Comment: Are there any other good solutions except for adding `from project(":MyProjectCore").sourceSets.main.output`?

Comment: For me, doing this gives an error: `Could not get unknown property 'sourceSets' for project ':shared' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

Answer (score 2):

With this you can add all *.class files created in your subprojects into your jar automatically:

```
jar {
    from {
        subprojects.collect { it.sourceSets.main.output }
    }
}
```

To make sure the .class are there, make sure the root project depends on the subprojects:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':mySubProject')
}
```